# Inverse of the covariant derivative

Tags: differential-geometry, differentiation, mathematics, calculus, covariance

Given the covariant derivative of some tensor, for the sake of this example a covariant vector:

$$\nabla_\mu A_\nu$$

Is there a well-defined inverse operation on the covariant derivative such that it will recover the original vector $A_\nu$? In other words, is there some sort of a "covariant integral" such that:

$$\int \nabla_\mu A_\nu dx^\mu =A_\nu$$

(I'm only using the notation for a regular integral because I couldn't think of any other way of writing it.)

Of course, this "covariant integral" will depend upon the rank of the term it is integrating, if it were to act on the covariant derivative of a scalar, or just the regular derivative of a scalar, then this "covariant integral" will just act as a regular integral.

If this "covariant integral" does exist, will it depend on the connection in some way?, or depend on the geometry in some other way?

Any further clarification on the subject and references to educational sources would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: May help you: https://arxiv.org/abs/physics/9802027

Comment: Hello @Amit, I have read this article and from what I understand it only talks about special cases where the covariant derivative of a tensor can be expressed as the regular derivative of the tensor density, in which case one can use the regular integral with the metric determinant to retrieve the original tensor. The article does not talk about a general case.

Comment: If by general you mean you want to recover a particular component of a vector field $V_\mu$ given its covariant derivative along an arbitrary direction $V_{\mu;\nu}$ then yeah I think you need to integrate also the connection coefficents.. maybe someone can correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I can suggest that you take a simple example like $S^2$ with the usual polar chart, so that you have non vanishing connection coefficents and test it out on a simple vector field :)

Comment: Note that since $V_{\mu,\nu} = V_{\mu;\nu} + \Gamma_{\mu\nu}^{\alpha}V_{\alpha}$ where note the sign is plus because we isolate the regular partial derivative on the LHS, it seems to me to follow that a regular integral on the RHS should recover the difference of the vector field between the two limits you integrate on

Comment: Last comment (sorry for the many comments): note that whenever you integrate a partial derivative, you have an added constant depending on the other directions you didn't integrate wrt. So you have to solve a system of equations in fact for the above with every $\nu$ to recover also the constants. See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/754742/integrating-a-partial-derivative

Comment: You might want to check out the [exterior derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative#) and its use in Stokes' theorem.

Comment: What you're looking for is the Green's function of the covariant derivative. Integrating the source w.r.t. the Green's function will then give you back the tensor you started with.

Comment: Are you looking for analytical solutions, and the conditions when they exist, or are you looking for numerical methods?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In essence, you need the Stokes theorem on differential forms, which is the generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus and is described in chapter B.2 of *General Relativity*, Wald, 1984. Integration with differential forms is the generalisation of the Green, Gauss and Stokes theorems in manifolds of arbitrary dimension, even without a metric.

In order to integrate a tensor, you must convert it into a differential form, as the volume element is a totally antisymmetric covariant tensor. An arbitrary tensor of order 2 can be written as the sum of a totally symmetric and a totally antisymmetric tensor; I'm not aware of a generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus for symmetric tensors.

Comment: While it is true that a type 2 tensor can be written as a symmetric tensor and an antisymmetric tensor, this does not generalize for higher type $n$. Abstractly, this is due to the representation theory of $\mathfrak S_n$, which has additional non trivial representations when $n>2$.

Comment: Take a tensor of type $n=3$ for example. The space of tensors is of dimension $d^3$, the space of symmetric tensors of dimension $\frac{d(d+1)(d+2)}{6}$ and the space of antisymmetric tensors of dimension $\frac{d(d-1)(d-2)}{6}$. The dimension don’t add up because you forgot the standard representation.

Comment: In any case, the integration of the $k-$form obtained by antisymmetrisation will not answer the question, since it is about the covariant derivative, not the exterior derivative. A curve integral of a $k-$form (which is what you need to invert the covariant derivative) is not more natural than one for a general tensor (for $k>1$).

Comment: Thank you, corrected. As the generalisation of the fundamental theorem of calculus is based on differential forms and the question is essentially about this theorem, the answer is relevant. Also, the exterior derivative can be written in terms of the covariant derivative.

Comment: I am curious to know if what I wrote in the OP comment is correct, at least for recovering the tensor up to a 'constant' function. I suggested to integrate the partial derivative in a 'naive' way that assumes knowledge of the covariant derivative value and the connection coefficents.

Comment: It looks correct at a glance, but it is rarely useful :) In most cases integration in relativity is required, differential forms and/or killing tensors are involved, as the spacetime or the tensors have manifest symmetry.

Comment: @auxsvr Thank you. I do agree it doesn't seem similar to the kind of integrals one usually tackles in GR. Perhaps it can be used to integrate a tensor field along a smooth curve (since a similar expression can be derived for the covariant derivative along a curve), but need to look more carefully into that to be sure.