# Integrating Differential equations in General relativity

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, integration, vector-fields

Let's say we have an equation of the form

\begin{equation}
\nabla _\vec{u}u^\mu(\tau)=F^\mu\big[x(\tau)\big]
\end{equation}

The operation on the left hand side is the usual covariant derivative along the worldline

\begin{equation}
\nabla_\vec{u}=u^\mu \nabla_\mu
\end{equation}

and $u$ is the usual 4-velocity

\begin{equation}
u^\mu\equiv \frac{dx^\mu}{d\tau}
\end{equation}

with $x(\tau)$ the trajectory of the particle and $\tau$ proper time along its worldline. The term in the right hand side is just a forcing term evaluated at the position of the particle. Its specific form is not relevant, only that it is a vector field evaluated on the worldline.

**My question is: Is there a sense in general relativity where we can integrate this to obtain the 4-velocity?**

I'm thinking something like

\begin{equation}
\int_{t_0}^{t_f}d\tau \nabla _\vec{u}u^\mu(\tau) = \int_{t_0}^{t_f}d\tau F^\mu\big[x(\tau)\big]\\
u^\mu(t_f)-u^\mu(t_0)=\int_{t_0}^{t_f}d\tau F^\mu\big[x(\tau)\big]
\end{equation}

I understand that integration of tensors is ill defined, but I'm wondering if there's some generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus or tensors in curved spacetime.

**EDIT:**

I am aware of the Stokes theorem in General relativity and integrating forms against a volume element. However, in my question I'm refering to integrating over proper time along a worldline, not integrating over spacetime. Also, I'd like the result to be $u^\mu$ with its index free, and not contracted with some normal versor.

**EDIT:**

If there's no such notion of integration. Then the question is: How do you find the 4-velocity given that differential equation? Do parallel propagators do the job?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/754798/inverse-of-the-covariant-derivative

Comment: No, integration of arbitrary tensor fields is not defined, and you shouldn’t expect it to be defined; you can’t add up vectors at different points. There is no “fundamental theorem of line integrals” in a naive sense. The only thing you have is Stokes’ theorem.

Comment: Thanks for your comment! I understand that, but then, is there a sense in which you can obtain the 4-velocity from that equation? Maybe using parallel propagators or something like that?

Comment: @P.C.Spaniel In the comments of the Q I linked to above, I mention that if somehow you have the component values of the covariant derivative $\nabla_\mu$ then the problem reduces to a simple integration of a multi variable function. However I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, i.e. what are you assuming has a *known* value in this differential equation you want to solve.

Comment: Once you write everything out, say in a local coordinate chart, you will get a (usually) coupled system of ODEs. One knows that abstractly, solutions to an initial-value problem exist and are unique. Solving them by hand is a pain, and unless a great deal of symmetry is present (eg geodesics for a sphere), it’s next to impossible to get a closed-form solution in terms of the familiar elementary (or even special) functions.